# How can I save an Excel 2016 file/table as an HTML file/table without any Javascript?

Tags: javascript, excel

I'm trying to allow a non technical user to save an excel table as an html table.  I have another webpage which will read the contents of the html file (via jQuery .load), so I need the html file to not have any Javascript.  Unfortunately Excel 2016 creates an htm file with scripts and dependent files when I do a save as htm (there is a folder created with 4 files and they use some Javascript)...  Any ideas on how to save as a basic html file or some solution I could use?  Do I need to find a macro?

Comment: You can **SaveAs** .html directly from Excel's menu system.

Comment: Yes, the SaveAs in Excel 2016 creates a parent html file with just javascript and a folder with two additional html files and xml file and a css file.  Unfortunately I need just a basic html file and not the extra garbage.  When I try to open just the sheet001.htm file (which has the html table) it redirects to the parent html file with the script... for my needs I can't have any script tags...